# Blue tyres for single speed

Tags: tire, single-speed

I need to change the tyres (700 x 25)  of my single speed and I am looking for some good quality tyres, preferably blue. Do you have any suggestion on what could be a good match, or where to look? Regarding delivery costs: I live in northern Europe.

Comment: So far as I know, the color of the tire does not affect the number of speeds that can be supported by the attached gearing.

Comment: Tyres should be black, for longevity reasons.  Non-black tyres lack an additive called "carbon black" which increases UV resistance.  So, if you have coloured tyres, store it out of the sunlight where possible.

Comment: Another thought - for tyres you don't really care about then give them a blast of blue spray paint.  Do it off the rims of course.   Expect the treat line to wear off in 100 metres, but the side walls should hold the colour for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be closed due to asking for opinion, but CST makes a tire called the Super HP in a wide variety of colors. I live in the states but am 99% sure you could find them across the waters as well. Another option from them would be the Czar:

http://www.csttires.com/int/bike/road-bike-tires/czar-c1406/

From my experience they are a decent affordable tire.